# Error on updating nvarchar(max) column from Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm updating the output of Google reverse geocoding (which is in JSON format),

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=test;PWD=abc@123;autocommit=True')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
wp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.5504,73.9412&sensor=false")
pw = wp.read()
#print(pw)
cursor.execute("UPDATE GEOCODE_tbl SET JSON_str = ? WHERE GEOCODE_ID = ?", pw,749904)
print('Done')
cnxn.commit()
```

But it gives error

```
('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: image is incompatible with nvarchar(max) (206) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

What kind of error is that?
The JSON_str column has such JSON output, so I'm executing the task for those column whose `JSON_str` column is NULL.

Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: Are you sure `pw` is of type `str`? Maybe try `cursor.execute("UPDATE GEOCODE_tbl SET JSON_str = ? WHERE GEOCODE_ID = ?", (str(pw), 749904))`?

Comment: @FlipperPA yes converting them to str worked. Thanks alot!!!

Comment: Great, I'll convert it to an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `pw` is not of type `str`. Try converting your query to this:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE GEOCODE_tbl SET JSON_str = ? WHERE GEOCODE_ID = ?", (str(pw), 749904))
```

Good luck!